# Primefaces how to fire another event after datatable select event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with selection and a commandbutton. Problem is If user doesn't select any item from datatable and clicks to button, selectedItem object returns null. I think datatable's selection event runs after my commandbutton's action method.

What i want to do is; 
If user Doesn't select any item from datatable and clicks the button, I will create a new SelectedItem object. But after button's action method runs, datatable changes it to null.

```
<p:panel id="panel1">
<p:dataTable selection="#{myController.selectedItem}"
             selectionMode="single"....
//some other stuff
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="panel2">
//some other stuff
<p:commandButton value="Create" action="myController.create"....
</p:panel>
```

My Controller;

```
SelectedItem selectedItem = new SelectedItem();

public void create(){
 selectedItem = new SelectedItem();
}
```

Comment: if user doesn't select, so which row is selected?

Comment: @Darka If user doesn't select, I want to create a new SelectedItem object. I mean if user doesn't select, I have nothing to do with datatable.But the problem is datatable changes my selectedItem to null after i click the button.

Comment: Sorry read one more time yours comment. If you want create new, you need add data to selectedItem = new SelectedItem(); something like selectedItem.setName('TOM');

Comment: change ACTION to actionListener and add Update dataTable

Comment: "selectedItem = new SelectedItem()" not equals "selectedItem = null"

Comment: @Darka changed action to actionListener and added update for datatable but still returns null

Comment: what scope you using?

Comment: I don't see, if you after creating selectedItem, add it to List, which you give to dataTable. Also can you give more source now? Also you can look at  BalusC [Example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: @Darka i will not add anything to List. I have Nothing to do with Datatable. I wont change anything at datatable. I wont get any data from datatable. I think you didn't understand the question

Comment: I guess so. But if you has nothing with datatable, why you write in question "But after button's action method runs, **datatable** changes it to null."

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
**.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable var="result" selection="#{myController.selectedItem}"
         selectionMode="single"....

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myController.create()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{result}" target="#{myController.selectedItem}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

**.java**

```
SelectedItem selectedItem = new SelectedItem();  

public void create(){
  selectedItem = new SelectedItem();
}
```

Comment: maybe, he means var from dataTable:   p:dataTable var="result"

Comment: `var` one of `p:dataTable` attribute, `var="result"`